# Azure cli command (az vm encryption show) returns substatus: null

Tags: azure, encryption, virtual-machine, azure-cli

I am using Azure disk encryption for centos 7.9 virtual machine. While encryption is in progress ssh to host is disabled. I want to determine if encryption has completed so I can perform other operations using ssh. From documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/virtual-machines/linux/how-to-verify-encryption-status) I see that there is a command:

```
 az vm encryption show --name ${VMNAME} --resource-group ${RGNAME} --query "substatus"
```

However in my case substatus returns value of null. Does anyone knows why az cli doesn't return proper message?

Here is the full output of command:

```
az vm encryption show --name ${VMNAME} --resource-group ${RGNAME}

{
  "disks": [
    {
      "encryptionSettings": [
        {
          "diskEncryptionKey": {
            "secretUrl": "sourceurl",
            "sourceVault": {
              "id": "vaultid"
            }
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "keyEncryptionKey": {
            "keyUrl": "keyurl",
            "sourceVault": {
              "id": "vaultid"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "name": "os_disk_name",
      "statuses": [
        {
          "code": "EncryptionState/encrypted",
          "displayStatus": "Encryption is enabled on disk",
          "level": "Info",
          "message": null,
          "time": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encryptionSettings": null,
      "name": "data_disk_name",
      "statuses": [
        {
          "code": "EncryptionState/notEncrypted",
          "displayStatus": "Disk is not encrypted",
          "level": "Info",
          "message": null,
          "time": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": null,
  "substatus": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have created a linux vm with  `centos 7.9 image` in our local environment, enabled the disk encryption on it by using the below cmdlet

```
az vm encryption enable -g "MyResourceGroup" --name "myVM" --disk-encryption-keyvault "<your-unique-keyvault-name>"
```

While encryption enable operation is in  progress we have lost the ssh session & we have tried querying the substatus of the encryption operation status by passing the `vmname` & `resourcegroup` parameters directly to the below cmdlet and able see the encryption substatus without any issues.

```
az vm encryption show --name <vmname> --resource-group <rgname> --query "substatus"
```

You can refer the below output screenshot for reference :

[image]

Below screenshot is from Azure cloud shell :

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Maybe the issue is that we are doing encryption through arm templates. However still, our returned substatus is null. It is weird, because on azure portal we see normal status, only this command not working correctly in our case.